# Top two days select for multiple rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a table with stock prices such as this:
[image: stock data sample]

I would like to do a SQL statement to get current latest price and the price before for a given stock ticker.

I can do that individually per stock, something like this:

```
  SELECT TOP 2 * FROM StockPrices WHERE TickerId = 'XASX:360' ORDER BY Date DESC
```

But for obvious reasons, this wouldn't work when there are multiple tickers.

I need something like this:

```
| TickerId  | Current CLOSE Price | Previous CLOSE Price |
| XASX:360  | 7.01                | 7.03                 |
| XASX:A200 | 123.92              | 123                  |
|  ....  etc .......                                     |
| XASX:AAC  | 1.38                | 1.365                |
```

An alternative would to even get just the latest date and the previous date.

```
| TickerId  | Current Trade Date | Previous Trade Date |
| XASX:360  | 2021-07-09         | 2021-07-08          |
| XASX:A200 | 2021-07-09         | 2021-07-08          |
| XASX:A2M  | 2021-07-09         | 2021-07-08          |
|  ....  etc .......                                   |
```

Notes about the data:

- The max date would the "current date" - but it doesn't mean it is today as weekends and holidays are not trading days and won't have prices against it.
- Previous Date is not CurrentDate - 1 for example, as it explained above the previous day could be a holiday or weekend.

Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your desired result set has the prices in separate columns rather than separate rows.  That suggests conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT TICKERID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEQNUM = 1 THEN CLOSEPRICE END) as CURRENT_CLOSEPRICE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN SEQNUM = 2 THEN CLOSEPRICE END) as  PREVIOUS_CLOSEPRICE,
       MAX(TICKERDATE) AS CURRENT_TRADEDATE,
       MIN(TICKERDATE) AS PREVIOUS_TRADEDATE
FROM (SELECT SP.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TICKERID ORDER BY TICKERDATE DESC) AS SEQNUM
      FROM STOCKPRICES SP
     ) SP
WHERE SEQNUM <= 2
GROUP BY TICKERID;
```

Then for performance, you can add an index on `(TICKERID, TICKERDATE DESC)`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The performance in my little 5 DTU Azure DB was 2 secs while the one with lead was 12 secs :)

Answer (score 1):

```
You can achieve you result using LEAD function in MS SQL SERVER. using following query just need to replace your column name from your table.     

SELECT 
            TICKERID,
            CURRENTCLOSEPRICE,
            PREVIOUSCLOSEPRICE 
            FROM ( 
                    SELECT 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TICKERID ORDER BY TICKERDATE DESC) AS SR,    
                        TICKERID,
                        CLOSEPRICE AS CURRENTCLOSEPRICE,
                        LEAD(CLOSEPRICE, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY TICKERID ORDER BY TICKERDATE DESC) AS PREVIOUSCLOSEPRICE
                        FROM STOCKPRICES 
            ) AS TBL 
    WHERE SR=1
```